# Standard Error as an estimator

Tags: variance, standard-error, estimators

The Standard Error is said to estimate the true standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the difference in the sample means.
But we also studied that estimators are calculated only for parameters and never statistics.
The difference in the sample is a statistic and surely not a parameter.
How is this justified?

Comment: We don’t estimate statistics. The terminology is important. Parameters are unknown, so we estimate them. Statistics are known with certainty (perhaps with some error because of numerical issues related to working on a computer in finite time).

Answer (score 1):

Standard error *is* the standard deviation of the sampling distribution (or, more specifically, the square root of the variance of the sampling distribution). As this goes, it is occasionally necessary to *estimate* the standard error (i.e. when the population standard deviation is not known). The issue here is context. Standard errors are a measure of spread for sample statistics (like the distribution of sample means for all samples of size $n$ from a population), whereas standard deviations are a measure of spread for population parameters (like the distribution of all individual values in a population).

Comment: Thankyou @Todd Burus. Should I begin by questioning the statement that 'Estimators are always calculated for parameters' or by trying to understand it?

Comment: I'm also confused on the part that you said that 'Standard error is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution' and I say that 'Standard Error estimates the true standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the difference in sample means. I feel that the two are different things.

Comment: @nisha If we don't know the true population standard deviation then we cannot calculate the true standard error of the sampling distribution. When this is the case, we have to estimate the standard error with the sample standard deviation, at which point we have an estimate for the standard error. In a sense this estimate of the standard error is an estimate of the standard deviation of the sampling distribution, but only because the true standard error is the true standard deviation of the sampling distribution (I understand how this language is confusing).